# How to update the axis scale on change events in cubism/d3

Tags: d3.js, cubism.js

I am trying to make a demonstration using cubism.  I have created a custom `context.metric`, similar to the `random()` function on the cubism homepage.  This loads my data set and renders correctly, showing a new row each second.

What I want to do now is have the axis scale domain update as well, using the date column from my dataset.  For the purposes of demonstration, I want each second that passes in wall-time to correspond to one row in my dataset, which is hourly.  I can set the scale domain when I create the context, but I cannot get it to update when new data is fetched.

I have tried to listen for context events such as `change`, and `beforechange` and manually update the domain there.  It does not seem to work, or I am doing something wrong.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the awesome libraries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context's time domain is fixed by the context step and size. For example, if you have a step of ten seconds and a size of 1,440, then the domain is the last four hours. If you use context.axis to display the axis, it will update automatically whenever the context fires a change event; you don't have to do anything. Cubism is designed for realtime dashboards, so it doesn't support advancing an hour per second.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.  I understand I am trying to do something outside of the cubism model... still was hoping it would be possible to accomplish by manually modifying the scale domain.  Thanks again.

Comment: I think you could do that, but you'd want to change the context implementation, not the axis.